# qemu KVM kernel module no such file or directory

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm

I am currently taking an operating systems class and I need to use qemu to run a small operating system that my professor provided. I am trying to use qemu within an ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine on virtualbox on my macbook air 5.2. I know the problems I am having probably have to do with nested virtualization but the specific error I get when I try to run qemu is:

> Could not access the KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
>
> failed to initialize KVM: no such file or directory
> Back to tcg accelerator.

qemu does start up the os but the window flickers quite a lot and I would like to fix the KVM problem if possible. I've done research but I can't find a solution I can understand or that works so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also for the ubuntu virtual machine in virtualbox I have both Enable VT-x/AMD-V and Enable Nested Paging checked under Hardware Virtualization. I've also tried using

```
modprobe kvm-intel
```

and I get this error:

> FATAL: Error inserting kvm_intel (/lib/modules.3.5.0-22-generic/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko): Operation not permitted.

Comment: This question would be more generic if it read 'Can I nest virtualization in a way that it supports qemu KVM?' or something like that, and not regarding your specific case. Remember, StackOverflow is more of a place for questions that may happen to anyone, not to you specifically.

Comment: just for reference, the errors `Could not access the KVM kernel module: No such file or directory failed to initialize KVM: no such file or directory Back to tcg accelerator.` are not unique to nested virtualization issues. I ran qemu on Ubuntu Precise (without virtualization) and it returned the same error (but then it continued and worked).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with `sudo modprobe kvm-intel`.

In order to have the module automatically loaded at the startup of the virtual machine, you can edit the file with any editor that allows you to edit files as `root`. You can use `sudoedit`, `vscode`, `sudo -e` or any other editor.

To keep the instructions straightforward, the following will work:

1. Edit the corresponding file from the shell with `sudo vi /etc/modules.conf`
2. Possibly enter your username password.
3. Press the key `G` to go to the end of the document and then `o` to begin inserting.
4. Write `kvm-intel` and press Enter, producing a new line.
5. Press `Esc` to return to the Normal mode of vim. "--INSERT--" will disappear from
   the bottom.
6. Save the file and exit `vim` by writing `:wq`.

You are done. Try to reboot and load the nested virtual machine.

Comment: I've already tried that, then it just says the same thing except operation not supported.

Comment: Operation not supported may mean that you can't actually do virtualization. Make sure your environment supports kvm by trying this command: `egrep '^flags.*(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo`. If there's no output, your virtual machine can't use KVM. Most probably nested virtualization isn't supported in KVM.

Comment: There isn't any output so I guess I won't be able to use kvm, thanks for your help though.

Comment: No problem. It seems that you can't actually use processor's Ring-0 even with VT-X. So, you'll need to go to your host OS to virtualize your professor's machine if you want it to have native performance. Or use an Ubuntu LiveCD instead of Ubuntu inside a VM. Or install it in a pendrive. There are lots of alternatives!

Comment: Can anyone help me do this on a machine with an AMD CPU? I'm running Linux Mint 17.1.

Answer (score 29):

In my case, the virtualization was disabled.

So `sudo modprobe kvm-intel` kept giving me the following error

> could not insert 'kvm_intel': Operation not supported

I just had to go in the BIOS and enable Virtualization.

Comment: Thank you! On my ThinkPad, I enabled specifically "Intel Virtualization Technology" under Security.

Comment: To verify, you can check `dmesg | grep kvm`. It will say `kvm: disabled by bios` if the setting is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I need to enable the "Intel Virtualization Technology" Under CPU section.  After enabled, one should see vcpu0.

Comment: In my case I had nested KVMs and it was turned off in the VM definition. Maybe this part `<model fallback='forbid'>qemu64</model>`. It can be changed by running virsh edit <vmname> and deleting that line. The VM needs to be restarted after making the change.