# can't run xv6 under Qemu

Tags: qemu, kvm, xv6

I want to boot `xv6`(unix based os) on `Qemu`.I compile It from source code and also install qemu but when I type `make qemu` in terminal I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-i386 -serial mon:stdio -hdb fs.img xv6.img -smp 2 -m 512 
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
Back to tcg accelerator.
```

but qemu runs (with flicks) and write : `no bootable device`[image]

I am also read [this discussion in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542754/qemu-kvm-kernel-module-no-such-file-or-directory) but doesn't solve my problem.
Note:first qemu can't find QEMU executable and according to [this link](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs422/2013/lec/l2-hw) I solve my problem by changing the `#QEMU=` with `QEMU = /usr/bin/qemu-system-i386` then I have this problem.

EDIT:I finally find the solution.my XV6 source code has a problem(that I don't know what?) then I download it from MIT OS course with this commands:

```
git clone git://pdos.csail.mit.edu/xv6/xv6.git
cd xv6/
make
qemu-system-i386 -serial mon:stdio -hdb fs.img xv6.img -smp 1 -m 512
```

Comment: http://amitks.github.io/blog/2013/02/08/installing-qemu-and-running-xv6/ I tried this and able to boot properly without any error that u facing

Comment: thanks I follow the link and finally run `sudo make qemu` but emulator window doesn't appear and I see `VNC server running on `127.0.0.1:5900'` instead of the `qemu` window

Comment: just run make qemu ... dont use sudo

Answer (score 0):

i had something similar. are you using a makefile perhaps when you compile?
from some reason for me it didn't recognize some of the time where the file sign.pl was because it was written "./sign.pl" and not /./sign.pl
also make sure to have all of your files with all of the permission required (for example: chmod 700 *)